# Is the expression 'more alike' awkward or does it work in an interface?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, expression-choice, phrase-requests

I want to create a button on an interface that will show me more items (cars) of the same kind (or similar in characteristics).

I was thinking of 'more like this' but this is a bit too long and the interface is already crowded, thus I came up with 'more alike', but I don't know if people understand this.

Alternatives are 'see similar cars' and 'other similar cars' but they are also too long.

How would it be more appropriate to say, in a short form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is a case where less is more, and you should try with either *"more..."* or skip the elipsis. If you think it is not explicit enough, maybe you could use *"similar cars"*, either as the actual text or as a tooltip. You can drop *see* or *other* without losing any meaning.

Comment: I would go with either "_more_" or if there is space "_see more_".

Comment: Are you saying 'more' is less is more?

Answer (score 4):

"More alike" is so confusing as to be wrong, IMHO.  Two pictures and a button saying 'more alike' would be comparing not the cars, but the similarities; these two are more alike... than the other two? than they are different?  than you'd expect?

Comment: +1 agree, I think. "More alike" means, to me, that these two things are more like each other than those two. Maybe not exactly what Tim is saying, I think, but that very fact indicates that the phrase is confusing.